# How to compute significance between powers of spectrum components (Fourier frequencies) of two EEG signals

Tags: statistical-significance, spectral-analysis

We have two EEG signals, and ran standard [NeuroDSP Spectral Analyses](https://neurodsp-tools.github.io/neurodsp/) to compute the power spectral densities of both signals. Moreover, because NeuroDSP uses standard Welch’s spectrogram and averages spectral density, we have coefficients of variation at each frequency for both signals too. The question is how to compute a statistical significance of the difference between two power spectral densities?

It seems obvious that such a method **must** exist, but 3 hours of googling didn't bring anything useful. I found a couple ideas, which don't seem right, [here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_can_I_compare_power_spectral_densities). Maybe I used the wrong keywords.

Comment: You probably have enough observations that you will be able to reject pretty much anything, so it will be critical to determine which differences are interesting to you. (This applies when sample sizes are small, too.)

Comment: @Dave, thanks for the note. Reality is different - there are some very different frequencies by eye, and there are not. We are looking for a well-established statistical method to compare this kind of stuff.

Comment: So what do you want to know? What differences interest you? You basically know that the spectra are at least a little bit different.

Comment: What does it mean for frequencies to be different?

Comment: Oops, sorry @Dave! I what to compute p-value (or something like that) and see at which  frequencies powers are significantly different. Also, how these powers are different from white noise. I believe that a standard p-test couldn't be applied, and specialized tests must exist.